Converting Arduino sketch with local Font to VSCode
I am trying to convert an Arduino Sketch to VSCode
I can't shake this compiling error!
src/main.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
src/main.cpp:12:20: error: 'HPSimplified27pt7b' was not declared in this scope    tft.setFreeFont(&HPSimplified27pt7b); 

I have copied the font file (HPSimplified27pt7b.h) to the "include" folder.
What am I missing here?
Probably a missing definition required by VSCode?
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>            // https://github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI
#include "HPSimplified27pt7b.h"  // My font...this file has been copied manually in the "include" folder

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();  // User_Setup_Select.h: Setup206_LilyGo_T_Display_S3.h

void setup() {
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_CYAN);
  tft.setFreeFont(&HPSimplified27pt7b);
  tft.setCursor(0, 100);
  tft.print("Screen");
}

void loop() {}


Here is plateformio.ini
    ; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:lilygo-t-display-s3]
platform = espressif32
board = lilygo-t-display-s3
framework = arduino
lib_deps = bodmer/TFT_eSPI@^2.5.43

